# CSS not loading since adding new id element to div class

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off what changed is I added two new divs and assigned it an id class of "order" and one "menuOutput".  Ever since then my CSS within the div id="menuOutput" has disappeared.  How do I get my CSS styles back whilst not changing how my js code works?  I know the new additions of the div are the problem but please tell me how to keep my styles with the new code?

```
<body>
<div id="order"></div>
<div id="menuOutput">
<h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="two">
      <h2>Pizza by the slice ($2)</h2>
      <input type="number" id="qty_slice of pizza">
      <h2>Toppings</h2>
      <p class="titles">Per Pepperoni($0.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_pepperoni">
      <p class="titles">Per Meatball($0.35):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_meatballs">
      <p class="titles">Per Mushhroom($0.40):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_mushrooms">
      <p class="titles">Per Olive($0.20):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_olives">
    </div>

    <div class="one">
      <h2>Sides</h2>
      <p class="titles">Potato Salad($1.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_potato salad">
      <p class="titles">Humus($2.50):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_hummus">
      <p class="titles">Caesar Salad($3.50):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_caesar salad">
      <p class="titles">Garden Salad($2.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_garden salad">
    </div>

    <div class="three">
        <h2>Drinks</h2>
        <div>

          <p class="titles">Small Soda($1.95):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_small">
          <p class="titles">Medium Soda($2.20):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_medium">
          <p class="titles">Large Soda($2.50):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_large">
        </div><hr>
      <p class="titles">Juice($2.00):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_juice">
      <p class="titles">Water($1.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_water">

    </div>
 </div><br>
 </div>
<div class="button">
  <button type class="button" id="submitOrder">Review Order</button>
</div>
<div id="order"></div>
<script src="./run.js"></script>
</body>

 ------------------------------------JS---------------------------
 //get menu from api
 var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status == 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
  } else {
    callback(status);
  }
};
xhr.send();
};

/*
{
"menu": {
"slice of pizza": "2.00",
qty_slice of pizza
"toppings": {
  "pepperoni": ".25",
  "meatballs": ".35",
  "mushrooms": ".40",
  "olives": ".20"
 },
 "sides": {
  "potato salad": "1.25",
  "hummus": "2.50",
  "caesar salad": "3.50",
  "garden salad": "2.25"
  },
  "drinks": {
  "soda": {
    "small": "1.95",
    "medium": "2.20",
    "large": "2.50"
   },
  "juice": "2.00",
  "water": "1.25"
  }
 }
 }
*/

 getJSON('https://mm214.com/menu.php', function(err, data) {
 if (err != null) {
 alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
 } else {

 var content = '';

 for (x in data.menu){
 if (typeof(data.menu[x]) == 'object'){
    for (y in data.menu[x]) {
        if (typeof(data.menu[x][y]) == 'object'){
            for (z in data.menu[x][y]) {
      content +=  z + ':' + data.menu[x][y][z] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + z + '"><br>';
            }
          }
            else {
      content += y + ':' + data.menu[x][y] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + y + '"><br>';
            }
        }//closes y in data

  }
  else 
  {
  content += x + ':' + data.menu[x] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + x + '"><br>';

  }//else for data.menu[x] if not an object
  }
  }//closes outer for loop

  //localStorage only stores strings! Stringify turns objects into strings!
  //parse converts JSON strings to objects that can be looped around

  document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = content;
  localStorage.setItem('order',JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(a + ':' + order[a]);

  var order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('order'));
  console.log(typeof(order));
  for (a in order){
  }

  });


  function storeOrder(){
   var pizzaqty = document.getElementById('qty_slice of pizza').value;
   localStorage.setItem('pizza',pizzaqty);
   var price  = pizzaqty * 2;


  }


  function retrieveOrder(){
    var pizzaordered = localStorage.getItem('pizza');


  }

  //output html
  //
  //document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = "Here is the menu: <br>" + data.menu;
  //why in't this working?

  //style menu for ordering
  //save order as json string
  //save in local storage
  //your order button

  //onclick: show order 
  document.getElementById('order').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('order1');

------------------CSS------------------------------

 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
 family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');

 .grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "one two three"
    "one two three";
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 165px);
 }

.title {
font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: teal;
}

input[type="number"] {
width: 40px;
}

.menu {
text-align: center;
}

.button {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
 }

.titles {
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.pizza {
text-align: center;
color: tomato;
background-color: teal;
}

.one {
grid-area: one;
background-color: #008c45;
text-align: center;
}


.two {
text-align: center;
grid-area: two;
background-color: #f4f5f0;
color: black;
}

.three {
grid-area: three;
text-align: center;
background-color: #cd212a;
}

h2 {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the CSS within the div has disappeared? What specifically isn't working because it seems fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/6zsq94mc/

Comment: ID should be unique in one page. You have added two div with same 'order' id.  One at the beginning and another one at the last.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I suspect is this line:

document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = content;

This basically says everything between the div with id "`menuOutput`" should now be the html in your `content` variable.

But nowhere in your `content` variable are you specifying the .grid, .one, .two, .three div classes.

Inspect the source code of the page: does `<div class="two">` exist?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember you can't have two identical ids in one page so you have to remove one of divs with id=order (I removed the one at the top). second, it seems you have added your classes in id attribute. we have two attributes for each element, id and class. you can add multiple classes for one element (e.g class="green blue red"), but you must have only one id which is unique in your page and can't include white spaces. (e.g id="blue_red"). at the end, I edited your code and removed the pizza from id and add it to the class and also corrected the values you have assigned to the elements and your css works fine again. you can run the snippet to see the result. wish it helps you:)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "one two three"
        "one two three"
        "one two three";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 165px);
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: teal;
}

input[type="number"] {
    width: 40px;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.titles {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.pizza {
    text-align: center;
    color: tomato;
    background-color: teal;
}

.one {
    grid-area: one;
    background-color: #008c45;
    text-align: center;
}


.two {
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: two;
    background-color: #f4f5f0;
    color: black;
}

.three {
    grid-area: three;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cd212a;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuOutput">
    <h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="two">
            <h2>Pizza by the slice ($2)</h2>
            <input type="number" class="pizza" id="qty_slice_of_pizza">
            <h2>Toppings</h2>
            <p class="titles">Per Pepperoni($0.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_pepperoni">
            <p class="titles">Per Meatball($0.35):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_meatballs">
            <p class="titles">Per Mushhroom($0.40):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_mushrooms">
            <p class="titles">Per Olive($0.20):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_olives">
        </div>

        <div class="one">
            <h2>Sides</h2>
            <p class="titles">Potato Salad($1.25):</p> <input type="number" class="salad" id="qty_potato_salad">
            <p class="titles">Humus($2.50):</p> <input type="number" class="salad" id="qty_hummus">
            <p class="titles">Caesar Salad($3.50):</p> <input type="number" class="salad" id="qty_caesar_salad">
            <p class="titles">Garden Salad($2.25):</p> <input type="number" class="salad" id="qty_garden_salad">
        </div>

        <div class="three">
            <h2>Drinks</h2>
            <div>

                <p class="titles">Small Soda($1.95):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_small">
                <p class="titles">Medium Soda($2.20):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_medium">
                <p class="titles">Large Soda($2.50):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_large">
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <p class="titles">Juice($2.00):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_juice">
            <p class="titles">Water($1.25):</p> <input type="number" id="qty_water">

        </div>
    </div>

    <br/>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <button type class="button" id="submitOrder">Review Order</button>
</div>
<div id="order"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is due to the **div** tags getting mixed up.

Here are the steps to resolve the problem:

1. Move the div tag meant for **menu-output** to the bottom of the page and add closure to it immediately.
2. Remove the duplicate div tags with same ID (menuOutput, order).

**Here is the working example with the div tags adjusted and duplicate divs removed:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu - demo</title>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');
            .grid {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-areas:
                "one two three"
                "one two three"
                "one two three";
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 165px);
            }

            .title {
                font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
                font-size: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                color: teal;
            }

            input[type="number"] {
                width: 40px;
            }

            .menu {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .button {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
                font-size: 25px;
            }

            .titles {
                font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
            }

            .pizza {
                text-align: center;
                color: tomato;
                background-color: teal;
            }

            .one {
                grid-area: one;
                background-color: #008c45;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .two {
                text-align: center;
                grid-area: two;
                background-color: #f4f5f0;
                color: black;
            }

            .three {
                grid-area: three;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #cd212a;
            }

            h2 {
                font-size: 30px;
                font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="order">
            <h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="two">
                    <h2>Pizza by the slice ($2)</h2>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_slice_of_pizza" />
                    <h2>Toppings</h2>
                    <p class="titles">Per Pepperoni($0.25):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_pepperoni">
                    <p class="titles">Per Meatball($0.35):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_meatballs">
                    <p class="titles">Per Mushroom($0.40):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_mushrooms">
                    <p class="titles">Per Olive($0.20):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_olives">
                </div>

                <div class="one">
                    <h2>Sides</h2>
                    <p class="titles">Potato Salad($1.25):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_potato_salad">
                    <p class="titles">Humus($2.50):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_hummus">
                    <p class="titles">Caesar Salad($3.50):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_caesar_salad">
                    <p class="titles">Garden Salad($2.25):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_garden_salad">
                </div>

                <div class="three">
                    <h2>Drinks</h2>
                    <p class="titles">Small Soda($1.95):</p> 
                    <input type="number" id="qty_small">
                    <p class="titles">Medium Soda($2.20):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_medium">
                    <p class="titles">Large Soda($2.50):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_large">
                    <p class="titles">Juice($2.00):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_juice">
                    <p class="titles">Water($1.25):</p>
                    <input type="number" id="qty_water">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" id="submitOrder">Review Order</button>
        </div>
        <div id="menuOutput"></div>
        <script>
            //get menu from api
             var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function() {
              var status = xhr.status;
              if (status == 200) {
                callback(null, xhr.response);
              } else {
                callback(status);
              }
            };
            xhr.send();
            };


            getJSON('https://mm214.com/menu.php', function(err, data) {
                if (err != null) {
                    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
                } else {

                var content = '';

                for (x in data.menu){
                    if (typeof(data.menu[x]) == 'object'){
                        for (y in data.menu[x]) {
                            if (typeof(data.menu[x][y]) == 'object'){
                                for (z in data.menu[x][y]) {
                                    content +=  z + ':' + data.menu[x][y][z] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + z + '"><br>';
                        }
                      }
                else {
                  content += y + ':' + data.menu[x][y] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + y + '"><br>';
                        }
                    }//closes y in data

              }
              else 
              {
              content += x + ':' + data.menu[x] + '<input type="number" id = "qty_' + x + '"><br>';

              }//else for data.menu[x] if not an object
              }
              }//closes outer for loop

              //localStorage only stores strings! Stringify turns objects into strings!
              //parse converts JSON strings to objects that can be looped around

              document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = content;
              localStorage.setItem('order',JSON.stringify(data));
              console.log(a + ':' + order[a]);

              var order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('order'));
              console.log(typeof(order));
              for (a in order){
              }

              });


              function storeOrder(){
               var pizzaqty = document.getElementById('qty_slice of pizza').value;
               localStorage.setItem('pizza',pizzaqty);
               var price  = pizzaqty * 2;


              }
              function retrieveOrder(){
                var pizzaordered = localStorage.getItem('pizza');

              }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]